# Network Analyst locked

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst

[image]I am using ArcMap10.3. And it looks like the network analyst is locked (see screenshot attached).

I have the license, and the network analyst is activated an it is working for the [tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-9-choosing-optimal-store-sites-using-location-allocation.htm) but it doesn't work on other maps.

Any idea about how I could unlock it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your screenshot

Comment: I don't see an attached screenshot. Is it possible someone else is/was using it (including yourself if you have another instance using it). You, or whoever is using it, may have to uncheck NA under Customize -> Extensions in the mxd using it. Alternately, if you have two different logins, one may have a license to use while another doesn't.

Comment: Have you added Network Dataset to the Data Frame? You can't perform any Network Analysis without it.

Comment: No, I though I could start without it and add it later, is there any way to import the Network Dataset from Open Street Map?

Comment: As far as I know you can't import Network Dataset from OSM. However you can download OSM routes to build your own Network Dataset. You can read about building NDs here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not locked. Just add a Network Dataset to the Data Frame. You can't perform any Network Analysis without one.